# How much does Java Graphics drawImage consume?

Tags: java, graphics

I was making an application in Java, and noticed after doing this:

```
g.drawImage(ImageIO.read(...)....);
```

that it consumed a lot more CPU and frames, so I started to wonder
**how much memory does this take up?** and if there were any other better ways to draw an image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the `drawImage` that's taking up a lot of CPU, it's the `ImageIO.read(…)`! Opening streams is expensive and thus should only be done once; when you first need to load the images. The best way to draw an image is to pre-load it into a `BufferedImage` (or if you manipulate the pixels a `VolatileImage`).

```
BufferedImage imageToDraw = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("path/To/Image.png"));
```

That path starts in the directory of your .java files. So, you'll want to add a folder containing your image(s). There are many different ways to load images, more of which are discussed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html).

Then you can draw it just like you did before.

```
g.drawImage(imageToDraw, x, y, null);
```

This should be *much* faster. If you are still having problems with speed then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658059/graphics-drawimage-in-java-is-extremely-slow-on-some-computers-yet-much-faster?rq=1) question might be useful.

Comment: Thank you! My application is better now :)

Comment: It also improved the frames by over 2700!

Comment: There's also the added overhead of translating the underlying image format into a `BufferedImage` +1

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is using visualvm:  http://visualvm.java.net.  I've used it with some success.

Quick steps:

- start your app locally
- start visualvm
- Tools > Options > Profiling > Misc (bottom) > Reset calibration data: Ok
- in VVM, connect to your app i.e., in left-hand frame, double-click on pkg.YourMainClass (pid 2112)
- Profiler tab, then click on Memory.

after initial baseline profiling is complete, you see a histogram of live objects.

You can take snapshots and compare them, set filters on packages, etc. See http://visualvm.java.net/docindex.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading the image rather than holding it as an instance of Image, you will be taking way too much memory up.

I highly, HIGHLY suggest to store the image as an instance of Image with ImageIO.read(params) rather than drawing it and reading it every single loop pass-through.

You'd most likely do it like this in your Canvas/JPanel/Swing Component class:

```
private Image myImage;

//Assume other code here

public void loadImages() {
     myImage = ImageIO.read(params);
     //load any other images
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
     g.drawImage(myImage, x, y, null);
}
```

Just like any other application, resources (images, data, etc) are all loaded at the start-up.

Comment: Thanks! This is handy too :)