# Graphics.drawImage() consumes a lot of memory drawing an int[] image

Tags: java, image, swing, memory, graphics

I have an ImageViewComponent that extends JComponent. This component is added to a JPanel that is added to a JFrame. From another class I regularly update the `int[] image` field of ImageViewComponent from another class. 
The problem is that this process eats up a lot of memory. It even consumes so much memory (+/- 130 MB after a few seconds according to JProfiler, and eventually it surpasses 1GB) that the entire program undergoes a 'lag spike' during garbage collection (the lag in the program happens at the same time that the memory is cleared).

This is the code of ImageViewComponent:

```
public class ImageViewComponent extends JComponent {

    private int image_width, image_height, updateInterval, updateCounter;
    private int[] imageArray;
    private BufferedImage currentDisplayedImage;
    private Image scaledDisplayedImage;

    /**
     * @param width          The width of this component
     * @param height         The height of this component
     * @param ui             The higher, the less frequent the image will be updated
     */
    public ImageViewComponent(int width, int height, int ui) {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        this.updateInterval = ui;
        this.updateCounter = 0;
        this.currentDisplayedImage = null;
        this.scaledDisplayedImage = null;
    }

    public void setImage(int[] image, int width, int height) {
        this.imageArray = image;
        this.image_width = width;
        this.image_height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        if (image_width == 0 || image_height == 0)
            return;
        else if (updateCounter != updateInterval && currentDisplayedImage != null) {
            g.drawImage(scaledDisplayedImage, 0, 0, this);
            updateCounter++;
            return;
        }

        this.currentDisplayedImage = new BufferedImage(image_width, image_height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        this.currentDisplayedImage.setRGB(0, 0, image_width, image_height, this.imageArray, 0, image_width);

        this.scaledDisplayedImage = this.currentDisplayedImage.getScaledInstance(this.getPreferredSize().width,
                this.getPreferredSize().height, BufferedImage.SCALE_DEFAULT);

        g.drawImage(scaledDisplayedImage, 0, 0, this);

        // reset update counter
        updateCounter = 0;
    }

}
```

JProfiler states that 70% of the program its active memory is allocated in this class, 50% is in `Graphics.drawImage` while 20% is in BufferedImage initialization.

I have tried fixing it by putting the line `this.currentDisplayedImage = new BufferedImage(image_width, image_height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)` in `setImage' and have it only set it once with a boolean flag but this makes the drawn image turn completely black for short amounts of time once in a while, nor does it fix the memory problem. 
I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/659533/2519947) suggestion, which didn't work either.

How can I fix this memory issue?

Comment: Avoid doing all  the work in the `paintComponent` method. Use a `ComponentListener` to detect changes to the component size and update the scaled instance then. I'd also create the new `BufferedImage` only in the `setImage` method, calling `repaint` to trigger a paint pass

Comment: @MadProgrammer The component itself doesn't change in size, nor does the image size. I rescale it because the `int[] image` has a bigger size than the component. The `setImage` method is called very often with each time a completely different image (it gets its images from a simulator that runs at approx. 60fps). I will create the `BufferedImage` in the `setImage` with a boolean flag to run in only once as I tried earlier. Anything else I should consider?

Comment: Provide a runnable example

Comment: I'd also verify that it's the component which is causing the memory leak and not what ever generates the `int[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with the code. Some refer to performance, others to style or best practices, and others (at least potentially) refer to memory consumption.

- Performance: The `getScaledInstance` method is distressingly slow. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32278737/3182664 and others for better alternatives
- Style: It's `imageWidth`, not `image_width`
- Best practices: For a `JComponent`, you usually, you override `paintComponent` and not `paint`
- Memory consumption: That's the main point...:

As MadProgrammer already pointed out: Do things as rarely as possible. The role and purpose of this `updateCounter` is not entirely clear. I think that the **responsibility** for updating the image less frequently should be in the class that *uses* your component - particularly, in the class that calls `updateImage` (which should simply be done less often). Maintaining this in the `paint` method is not very reliable.

In your current code, it seems like the `currentDisplayedImage` is (despite its name) neither *displayed* nor *used* in any other way. It may, however, be a good idea to keep it: It will be needed to be filled with the `int[]` data, and as a source for the scaled image that might have to be created.

One possible implementation of your class might look as follows:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class ImageViewComponent extends JComponent {

    private int updateInterval, updateCounter;
    private BufferedImage fullImage;
    private BufferedImage displayedImage;

    /**
     * @param width          The width of this component
     * @param height         The height of this component
     * @param ui             The higher, the less frequent the image will be updated
     */
    public ImageViewComponent(int width, int height, int ui) {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        this.updateInterval = ui;
        this.updateCounter = 0;
        this.fullImage = null;
        this.displayedImage = 
            new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    }

    public void setImage(int[] image, int width, int height) {

        // Note: The updateInvervall/updateCounter stuff COULD
        // probably also be done here...
        if (fullImage == null ||
            fullImage.getWidth() != width ||
            fullImage.getHeight() != height)
        {
            fullImage = new BufferedImage(
                width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        }
        fullImage.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, image, 0, width);
        scaleImage(fullImage, displayedImage);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(displayedImage, 0, 0, this);
    }


    private static BufferedImage scaleImage(
        BufferedImage input, BufferedImage output)
    {
        double scaleX = (double) output.getWidth() / input.getWidth();
        double scaleY = (double) output.getHeight() / input.getHeight();
        AffineTransform affineTransform = 
            AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scaleX, scaleY);
        AffineTransformOp affineTransformOp = 
            new AffineTransformOp(affineTransform, null);
        return affineTransformOp.filter(input, output);
    }    

}
```

but **note** that this does **not** do this "updateInterval" handling, for the reason mentioned above.

And a side note: Maybe you don't even have to scale the image. If your intention is to have the image always being displayed *at the size of the component*, then you can simply do

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    // Draw the FULL image, which, regardless of its size (!) 
    // is here painted to just fill this component:
    g.drawImage(fullImage, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
}
```

Usually, drawing a scaled image like this is pretty fast. But depending on many factors, separating the step of scaling and painting the image, like you did, may also be a reasonable option.

Comment: Using your suggestion in combination with calling `setImage` in an `invokeLater` block in the calling method fixed the memory issue. FYI the last part of your post (separating scaling and painting) didn't seem to make much of a difference, if any. Thanks!